# Ubuntu 18.04 inconsistent scrolling behavior

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

Issue: When the touch-pad is touched with two fingers the page will scroll to the very top or bottom of the page.

How to reproduce: I open an application for example chrome, and scroll half way between the top and bottom of the page. I then go to another application lets say visual studio code, I then do some scrolling up and down with two fingers on the touch-pad. I then go back to chrome. The moment I touch two fingers to the touch-pad the page will be scrolled to the top or bottom of the page.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @K7AAY I tried Kubuntu 19.10 and was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @K7AAY I was not able to reproduce the issue on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: So, it is specific to a post-installation configuration change of Ubuntu 19.10, and not specific to your hardware. I wish I knew how to direct your troubleshooting from here, but I don't, but at least we have isolated the nature of the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. This might be a silly thought but would it be useful to test Ubuntu 18.04 off of a thumb-drive?

Comment: I frequently get sudden scrolling when switching between apps - and it happens with my mouse. I just assumed my mouse had a fault! I alt-tab to another app and as soon as I touch the wheel it shoots up the page. It only happens occasionally, maybe twice a day. _Update_: just tested alt-tabbing with my touchpad two-finger scrolling and it 100% reliably does this. Only jumps a few inches up but it's very jarring! Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Thinkpad Carbon X1

Comment: I no longer have this issue. I am amusing that it was resolved during a software update.